# Remove properties from files in powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to remove all properties (title, author, camera,...) from files in one folder with PowerShell (in Windows 10). Is that even possible or any simple command to do that or would I need to remove each property one by one?

Comment: What kind of files? Looks like you want to remove exif information from image files

Comment: From image and maybe also PDF files, word documents. But at least photos will be enough if others are different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a simple one-off solution or occasional solution Windows explorer has this function built-in.

1. Select all your files in the folder.
2. Right click one and select Properties then Details tab.
3. Bottom of Properties has "Remove Properties and Personal Information"
   --Has options to create copies of files with properties removed
   or remove from active files. Select properties individually or Select All.

[image: Remove Meta]

Comment: I need this to be done with PowerShell command.